# ajax get to MVC method not passing parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, get

I have jquery function which looks like this

```
    function MonitorLoadStatus(loadId) {
     var url = 'LoadAdmin/GetLoadStatus/' + loadId;
     $.get(url, function (data) {
         if (data != "complete") {                 
             $("img[id =" + loadId + "]").show();
             window.setTimeout(function () {
                 MonitorLoadStatus(loadId);
             }, 1000);

         }
         else {
             $("img[id =" + loadId + "]").hide();
         };
     });
 }
```

and an MVC method which looks like this

```
public ActionResult GetLoadStatus(string loadId)
    {
        // check some thing and return stuff
        return Content(currentProgress);
    }
```

The loadid to the above method is being passed as null from the jquery get method. What exactly am i doing wrong

Comment: is your loadId valid, did you try doing console.log(loadId); before $.get() method...?

Comment: yes loadId is getting passed correctly before the $.get() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a route in your Global.asax which has a `/{loadId}` at the end. I remind you that the default route looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

meaning that the parameter should be called `id` in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetLoadStatus(string id)
{
    // check some thing and return stuff
    return Content(currentProgress);
}
```

If you want to use `loadId` update your route definitions accordingly.